# Evaluating boolean expression across Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame "data" with columns that include "cond1", "cond2", "cond3", "cond4", "cond5", "cond6", "cond7" that each contain True/False

I would like to add another column, table["condMet"] that will contain True/False depending on whether all 7 conditions are met.

Currently I have this which achieves this purpose:

```
data["condMet"] = (data.cond1 == True) & (data.cond2 == True) &    (data.cond3     == True) & (data.cond4 == True) & (data.cond5 == True) & (data.cond6 == True) &  (data.cond7 == True)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? E.g. I can select these columns only by doing

```
data.iloc[:,5:12]
```

How can I now slice this to include only rows where all colums are TRUE?

Comment: data.ix[data.condMet, 5:12]

Comment: @lowtech: What he wants is an easier way to create `condMet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DataFrame where all columns are booleans (like the slice you mention at the end of your question, you could apply `all` to it row-wise:

```
d = data.iloc[:, 5:12]
d[d.all(axis=1)]
```

This will select rows where all columns have a boolean-true value.

If you just want the boolean column that tells you whether the rows are included, that's just `d.all(axis=1)`.

Comment: `d[d.all(axis=1)]` or some variant is likely to be faster for large frames.

Comment: @DSM: Oops, you're right, I forgot `all` was available as a method.  I edited my answer.

Comment: ok this will select the appropriate rows, now how to create a new column data["condMet"] that displays True or False depending on whether the each row is in this subset?

Comment: @baconwichsand: That's just the `d.all(axis=1)` part inside that expression.  (I edited my answer to mention this.)